# Performing a geometric construction symbolically

Tags: symbolic, geometry

I'm trying to get a formula to build a conic with the construction of William Braikenridge and Colin MacLaurin.

When performing the construction I want to use symbolics, because I want the final result to be the formula for the construction.

So I tried to build two general lines:

```
A2 = Point[{Subscript[a, x], Subscript[a, y]}];
B2 = Point[{Subscript[b, x], Subscript[b, y]}];
D2 = Point[{Subscript[d, x], Subscript[d, y]}];
E2 = Point[{Subscript[e, x], Subscript[e, y]}];
r = Line[{{A2, D2}}];
s = Line[{{B2, E2}}];
```

But I can't see how to get access to the equations of the lines, and I need the symbolic expression for their intersection. Of course, I could do it all on the paper, but that would be tedious, because I have to build other lines and get other intersections.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to work just with the determinants, thank you.

Comment: `RegionIntersection[r, s]`?  It's not clear how far this can be pushed, though...

Comment: I think Mathematica does not have symbolic geometry as advanced as you are looking for. I am not sure if there are packages that can do it.

Comment: Ok, i'll do part of the job with paper and the other with mathematica.

Comment: `InterpolatingPolynomial[]` ("how to get access to the equations of the lines") and `LinearSolve[]` ("I need the symbolic expression for their intersection") ought to be useful here.

Comment: LinearSolve and Solve just give me the trivial solution.

Comment: Try this: `{\[FormalX], \[FormalY]} /. First @ Solve[{\[FormalY] == InterpolatingPolynomial[{{Subscript[a, x], Subscript[a, y]}, {Subscript[d, x], Subscript[d, y]}}, \[FormalX]], \[FormalY] == InterpolatingPolynomial[{{Subscript[b, x], Subscript[b, y]}, {Subscript[e, x], Subscript[e, y]}}, \[FormalX]]}, {\[FormalX], \[FormalY]}]`

Answer (score 5):

```
Format[a[x_]] := Subscript[a, x];
Format[b[x_]] := Subscript[b, x];
Format[d[x_]] := Subscript[d, x];
Format[e[x_]] := Subscript[e, x];

A2 = a /@ {"x", "y"};
B2 = b /@ {"x", "y"};
D2 = d /@ {"x", "y"};
E2 = e /@ {"x", "y"};
```

The equation for the line passing through the points `A2` and `D2`

```
r = Simplify[
   m*x + b /. Solve[#[[2]] == m*#[[1]] + b & /@ {A2, D2}, {m, b}][[1]]];
```

Similarly, the equation for the line passing through the points `B2` and `E2`

```
s = Simplify[
   m*x + b /. Solve[#[[2]] == m*#[[1]] + b & /@ {B2, E2}, {m, b}][[1]]];
```

The intersection point is

```
ip = {x, r} /. Solve[r == s, x][[1]] // Simplify
```

[image]

As expected, you get the same result using `s` rather than `r`

```
ip == {x, s} /. Solve[r == s, x][[1]] // Simplify

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: Thank you Bob, your code is being really useful.